# How to combine two arrays together?

Tags: php, arrays, merge, key

Is there a quick way to combine one arrays values as the other array's keys?

Input:

```
array A => Array (
        [0] => "cat"
        [1] => "bat"
        [2] => "hat"
        [3] => "mat"
    )

array B => Array (
        [0] => "fur"
        [1] => "ball"
        [2] => "clothes"
        [3] => "home"
    )
```

Expected output:

```
array C => Array (
        [cat] => "fur"
        [bat] => "ball"
        [hat] => "clothes"
        [mat] => "home"
    )
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[**`array_combine()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) will exactly do what you want.

Quoting the manual:

> ```
> array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )
> ```
>
> Creates an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and the values from the values array as the corresponding values.

In your case, you'd have to do something like this:

```
$array['C'] = array_combine($array['A'], $array['B']);
```

---

While of course you could also use various combinations of loops to do that, `array_combine()` is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: I have just login on SO specially for write my comment here and for giving my up votes and my comment is: YOU ARE ROCK!! MAN :) Thanks, I was just trying to read data from excel file and I made my insert query by your answer. Thanks again....

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply with [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine):

```
// First parameter will be used as the keys, the second for the values
$new_array = array_combine($keys_array, $values_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `array_combine($a, $b);`