# Combining the keys and values of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merging PHP array, one as Keys the other as Values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422955/merging-php-array-one-as-keys-the-other-as-values)

I have the following two arrays in PHP, which represent atmospheric gases and their compositions:

```
Array
(
    [0] => nitrogen
    [1] => argon
    [2] => oxygen
    [3] => carbon dioxide
)

Array
(
    [0] => 78
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 21
    [3] => 0
)
```

Is there an elegant way of obtaining the following array, a combination of keys and values:

```
Array
(
    "nitrogen" => 78
    "argon" => 1
    "oxygen" => 21
    "carbon dioxide" => 0
)
```

The methods I can think of involve loops, I don't know if I'm complicating it.  Is there a simple way?

Comment: array_combine() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), simply:

```
$new_arr = array_combine($keys,$values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not - `array_combine()` exists and is *exactly* what you are looking for!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

> array_combine — Creates an array by using one array for keys and
>   another for its values

---

Example adapted from the above link -

```
$a = array('Stack', 'Server', 'Super');
$b = array('Overflow', 'Fault', 'User');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);

Array
(
    [Stack] => Overflow
    [Server] => Fault
    [Super] => User
)
```

And there you have it - an array fit for a [tr](https://stackoverflow.com/)[il](https://serverfault.com/)[ogy](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Let's see [them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here) scrape our content now ;)

Answer (score 1):

use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
$key = array('nitrogen', 'argon', 'oxygen', 'carbon dioxide');
$values = array(78, 1, 21, 0 );

$return = array_combine($key, $values);

print_r($return);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [nitrogen] => 78
    [argon] => 1
    [oxygen] => 21
    [carbon dioxide] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

array_combine() Example:

```
<?php
print_r(array_combine(Array('a','a','b'), Array(1,2,3)));
?>
```

Returns:
Array
(
    [a] => 2
    [b] => 3
)

If two keys are the same, the second one prevails.