# how to make the value of an array as the keys of the values of another array in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merging PHP array, one as Keys the other as Values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422955/merging-php-array-one-as-keys-the-other-as-values)

i have an array of keys, and i have an array of values..how to make the values of arrray A, as the "keys" of the values of array B ?

```
array A

   [0] => 224
    [1] => 77
    [2] => 78
    [3] => 79
    [4] => 80
    [5] => 81
    [6] => 82
    [7] => 76
)
1

array B

Array
(
    [0] => Men Shoes
    [1] => Fashion Accessories
    [2] => Men Apparels
    [3] => Shoes & Belts
    [4] => Watches & Clocks
    [5] => Women Apparels
    [6] => Others
    [7] => Bags
```

what i want to happen is make it like this

```
array(
 [224] => Men Shoes
 [77] => Fashion Accessories
 [78] => Men Apparells
 [79] => Shoes & Belts
 [80] => Watches & clocks
 [81] => Women Apparels
 [82] => Others
 [76] => Bags 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

> Creates an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and
>   the values from the values array as the corresponding values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Sample code for you.

```
<?PHP
$array_a = array
(
    0 => 224,
    1 => 77,
    2 => 78,
    3 => 79,
    4 => 80,
    5 => 81,
    6 => 82,
    7 => 76
);

$array_b = array
(
    0 => "Men Shoes",
    1 => "Fashion Accessories",
    2 => "Men Apparels",
    3 => "Shoes & Belts",
    4 => "Watches & Clocks",
    5 => "Women Apparels",
    6 => "Others",
    7 => "Bags"
);

$new_array = array_combine($array_a,$array_b);

print_r($new_array);

?>
```