# PHP Turn value from multidimensional array into an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm getting an array from $json_a = json_decode($filecontent, true):

```
Array (
        [meta_titles] => Array ( 
                [0] => Just another site 
                [1] => Test test 
                [2] => This is a test
        )
        [tag_titles] => Array ( 
                [0] => Test 1 
                [1] => Value 2 
                [2] => String 3
        )
)
```

I would like to modify the array as following:

```
Array (
        [meta_titles] => Array ( 
                Just another site => Just another site 
                Test test  => Test test 
                This is a test => This is a test
        )
        [tag_titles] => Array ( 
                Test 1 => Test 1 
                Value 2  => Value 2 
                String 3 => String 3
        )
    )
```

So values become the keys. Would somebody have an idea?

EDIT: My code so far:

```
$json_a = json_decode($filecontent, true);

$newjson = array();
foreach($json_a as $category) {
    $newjson[$category] = array_combine(array_values($category), $category);
}                           
$json = json_encode($newjson, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Euh your link brings me to "What does “1” mean at the end of a php print_r statement?" which has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Wups yes, somehow I didn't copied the correct link. I mean this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5422955/3933332 just use the same subArray for keys and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using `array_combine` and `array_values` functions. To change array value in place mark it as reference with `&`:

```
$json = [ 
    'meta_titles' => [ 0 => 'Just another site' , 1 => 'Test test' , 2 => 'This is a test'],
    'tag_titles' => [ 0 => 'Test 1' , 1 => 'Value 2' , 2 => 'String 3']    
];

foreach($json as &$category) {
    $category = array_combine(array_values($category), $category);
}

$json = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

print_r($json);
```

The output:

```
{
    "meta_titles": {
        "Just another site": "Just another site",
        "Test test": "Test test",
        "This is a test": "This is a test"
    },
    "tag_titles": {
        "Test 1": "Test 1",
        "Value 2": "Value 2",
        "String 3": "String 3"
    }
}
```

Comment: meta_titles is dynamic though, there are other array names in it...Should I do it in a foreach loop?

Comment: update your question according to this condition "there are other array names in it.", update the expected output, and I will extend my solution for you

Comment: @GuilVII, each parent key should be renamed to `meta_titles` , right (it's in your example)?

Comment: Sorry I edited again, parent keys should remain the same.

Comment: Working like a charm! Quick question, can I use same part of code to return "Title Test": "" instead of "Title Test": "Title Test" so attributing an empty string? Thanks a lot anyway!!!

Comment: do you want to get same arrays with string keys but empty values?

Comment: Yes exactly what I want! I mean I need both but can't figure out how to do without another foreach loop...

Comment: wait, what does mean "need both"? the values are either filled or empty, or you want to mix up filling values randomly?

Comment: But yes you got what I would like to do, turn [0] => Just another site into Just another site => ""

Comment: I would say that it should be a new question in SO. In that case, there must exist some preconditions,  depending on which condition, I should decide which value would be empty, and which - should be filled

Comment: All value have to be empty...Strings become keys with empty strings. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: If so, use this simple trick: `$category = array_combine(array_values($category), array_fill(0, count($category),""));` It should work as you expected

Comment: I'm glad to be useful for the people who really needs help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = array (
    'meta_titles' => array ( 
            0 => 'Just another site',
            1 => 'Test test' ,
            2 => 'This is a test'
    )
);

$new_array['meta_titles'] = array();

foreach($array['meta_titles'] as $v) {
   $new_array['meta_titles'][$v] = $v;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
```

This gives:

```
Array
(
 [meta_titles] => Array
    (
        [Just another site] => Just another site
        [Test test] => Test test
        [This is a test] => This is a test
    )

)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. meta_title is supposed to be dynamic though...I tried: foreach($json_a as $category) {
      foreach($category as $string){           
          $json_a[$category][$string] = $string;
      } but it's not changing the key...
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can try. `reset($youArr);` for get array like this

```
{ 
  Array {
          0 =》title
          1=》 description
           2 =》keywords
           }
}
```

And how to you can use array don't know keys?

Comment: Key is supposed to be equal to the value key => key. So json encode returns "Value":"Value".

Comment: @GuilVll if return 0,1,2. I can use this jast `res[0]` if value = value I need use loop for get each element...